# How to do UV Mapping in shape bottle

Tags: uv

How to do UV Mapping for a bottle shaped like this?

[image]

Comment: You can select the vertical edges and mark seam them by right clicking.

Answer (score 1):

Cylindrical UV unwrapping should do the job as the model resembles a cylinder and the topology is quads.  Unwrapped cylindrically, they are rectangles.